# VIM syntax: conditional function coloring

Tags: c, function, vim, syntax

I'm customizing the standard "c.vim" syntax file in order to tune the visualisation of my C code.
I would like to distinguish the color of the "called functions" from the one of the "declared functions".

Exemple:

```
int declared_function()
{
    int m;

    m = called_function();
    return (m)
}
```

I read in depth the VIM documentation, and millions of forums and google results, but all the solutions I tried didn't work.

To resume, I did this:

I defined a region in a recursive way in order to consider all the code within the braces:

```
syn region Body start="{" end="}" contains=Body
```

Then I defined through VIM patterns a general function syntax:

```
syn match cFunction "\<\h\w*\>\(\s\|\n\)*("me=e-1 contains=cType,cDelimiter,cDefine
```

I did this because I thought I could combine the two in a "if else" condition in the .vimrc file... but after a whole day of failing tests I need the help of someone, who can tell me if it's possible and how to do it.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. First, you don't need the recursive definition, but contain all other top-level C syntax elements in it, plus the special group you'll define for called functions:

```
:syn region Body start="{" end="}" contains=TOP,cFunctionUse
```

Actually, scratch that, the default `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim` already defines a `cBlock` syntax group.

Then, define a *different* syntax group that is contained in the `cBlock` group.

```
:syn match cFunctionUse "\<\h\w*\>\(\s\|\n\)*("me=e-1 contained containedin=cBlock contains=cType,cDelimiter,cDefine
```

Finally, link or define a different highlight group for it, so that it actually looks different:

```
:hi link cFunctionUse Special
```

You can put those into `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`, so that they'll be added automatically to the default C syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But it still doesn't work. I still have all the functions of the same color (but I learnt the use of TOP)

Comment: Sorry about that; I have additional syntax definitions that have fooled me. Actually, the solution is even simpler, as there's already a `cBlock` group, so you don't need `Body` at all! See my updated answer.

Comment: Yep. It works and it's more elegant than my workaround (I kept the recursive form and I added by hand all the stuff I needed, taking inspiration from your hint). But your solution is definitely smarter: I will implement it tomorrow. Finally, after having worked out the whole syntax doc, I find vim even more powerful than what I imagined.

Comment: Finally, it doesn't work. I think the problem is namely cBlock as defined in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim   If you try to assigne to it a different background (like gtermbg=11) you can see that it doesn't underline properly what it is supposed to underline.On the contrary if I define a region (for ex. Body as I did) it underlines exclusively the functions' body/

Comment: Isn't the highlighting issue rather that cBlock is defined with `transparent` by default?! As you can see, this task isn't trivial; maybe you should rethink whether that's really worth it?!